# How to make redirection with variable URL

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have a form on my page an there is a problem with `PHP/JS` redirect.

I have 3 conditions:

1. I can't use `PHP` "header location" to redirect because I need the page not to be refreshed on form submit, so I defined button `type='button`', NOT type='submit' and I'm using `AJAX`.
2. I can't define redirection URL in `AJAX's` "success", because the URL should be variable, depending on previous user's actions. So I need to define the URL in `PHP`.
3. I have to define URL only after user has clicked on the button on my page, not before.

The problem is, that JS doesn't see the URL defined in PHP, so redirection doesn't work (If I define the URL in `AJAX's` "success", then it works fine).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my_button").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'file.php',
                  data: {check_button: '1', email: 'user@email.com'},
                  success: function(data){
                    //var url = "https://..................";   // THIS WORKS FINE!
                    var url = document.getElementById("my_url").value;    // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
                      window.location.href=url;
                  }
        });
    });
});
```

```php
// echo "<input type='hidden' id='my_url' value='https://................'/>"; // THIS WORKS FINE!
if (isset($_POST['check_button'])) { 
  echo "<input type='hidden' id='my_url' value='https://................'/>";  // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
  // Do something
}
```

And I need to define the URL exactly in this statement. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Return the value of the url from PHP in ajax response and then set it.

Comment: Also kindly post your PHP code.

Comment: Yes I have done that, I passed the url to js in hidden tag, and then I have set it in ajax, but this only works if I'm passing the variable BEFORE the user has clicked on the button

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change in PHP code :

```
if (isset($_POST['check_button'])) 
{ 
  echo "https://................"; // URL you want
}
```

Then make the following change in Ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'file.php',
data: {check_button: '1', email: 'user@email.com'},
success: function(data)
{        
    window.location.href=data;
}
});
```

Comment: This works, thank you! But if I have another echo in this php file, then all these outputs will be transfered to ajax... Maybe there is another way?

Comment: if there are multiple values then you can put them into an array and then echo them using json_encode().